# SQL sum and subtract issue with two queries

Tags: sql, db2

OK, I need somehelp. I have the following two queries:

```
SELECT DA.OWNG_OCD AS OFFICE, 'FL' AS STATE, SUM(S.STK_END_SEQ_NUM -
S.STK_STRT_SEQ_NUM) + COUNT(*) AS TOTSTK FROM STKRNG S, DFACCT DA, CMPNT C 
WHERE RANGE_USED_SW = 'N' AND S.DFTACCT_CANUM = DA.DFTACCT_CANUM
AND DA.OWNG_OCD = C.OCD AND C.ST = 'FL' AND S.STK_TYP = 'R' GROUP   
BY DA.OWNG_OCD;
```

AND

```
SELECT C.OCD, COUNT(*) AS USED FROM DRAFT D
JOIN STKRNG S ON S.DFTACCT_CANUM = D.DFTACCT_CANUM
JOIN DFACCT DA ON S.DFTACCT_CANUM = DA.DFTACCT_CANUM
JOIN CMPNT C ON CMPNT.OCD = DA.OWNG_OCD
WHERE D.DRFT_SEQ_NUM >= (SELECT MIN(S.STK_STRT_SEQ_NUM) FROM STKRNG S 
WHERE D.DFTACCT_CANUM = S.DFTACCT_CANUM AND S.RANGE_USED_SW = 'N') 
AND  D.DRFT_SEQ_NUM <= (SELECT MAX(S.STK_END_SEQ_NUM) FROM STKRNG S WHERE   
D.DFTACCT_CANUM = S.DFTACCT_CANUM  AND S.RANGE_USED_SW = 'N')
AND S.STK_TYP = 'R'
AND S.RANGE_USED_SW = 'N'
AND C.ST = 'FL'
GROUP BY C.OCD;
```

I am trying to write one query where the results of the COUNT in the second query are subtracted from the results of the COUNT in the first query. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your queries in the from clause of your final query:

```
select q1.totstk - q2.used
from ( <your first query here> ) q1
join ( <your second query here> ) q2 on q2.ocd = q1.office;
```

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this:

```
with STKRNGMINMAX as (
SELECT S.DFTACCT_CANUM, 
MIN(S.STK_STRT_SEQ_NUM) MINNUM, MAX(S.STK_END_SEQ_NUM) MAXNUM, 
SUM(S.STK_END_SEQ_NUM - S.STK_STRT_SEQ_NUM) DIFFNUM  
FROM STKRNG S 
WHERE (S.RANGE_USED_SW, S.STK_TYP)=('N', 'R')
group by S.DFTACCT_CANUM
)
SELECT C.OCD, S.DIFFNUM - COUNT(*) AS TOTSTK,  
FROM DRAFT D
INNER JOIN STKRNGMINMAX S ON S.DFTACCT_CANUM = D.DFTACCT_CANUM and D.DRFT_SEQ_NUM between S.MINNUM AND S.MAXNUM 
INNER JOIN DFACCT DA ON S.DFTACCT_CANUM = DA.DFTACCT_CANUM
INNER JOIN CMPNT C ON C.OCD = DA.OWNG_OCD and  C.ST='FL'
GROUP BY C.OCD;
```